# Detecting rotated, scaled, re-colored images using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I've recently come across a new type of captcha and am just curious about how someone would go about writing code in Python and OpenCV to solve it.

I'm a beginner in the field of image processing and am reading a lot about it online. I've written some basic code to solve some simple text-based captchas, but this one has me stumped. If you notice, the objects have a lot of properties modified i.e. they've been scaled, rotated, made transparent, re-colored (change of hue, saturation, brightness etc.) and possibly more.

This seemed similar to solving ReCaptcha, so I read up about that. It seems the most common way to solve something like this is to use a neural network and some form of learning algorithm. I'm interested where I could learn more about this.

However, what if I don't have enough training images to actually make a learning algorithm possible? If I have only 100 or 200 images, that wouldn't be enough. What can be done in this situation?

I am a beginner here, so please forgive my lack of knowledge here. Also request you to answer keeping this in mind.

[image: Example Captcha]

Comment: Try feature mapping. Find the keypoints and descriptors in the images and get the matches.

Comment: What you are after is called *template matching*, here with scaling and rotation. I have not checked, but it seems that the scaling is always the same, which eases the problem. To deal with color changes, you can just turn the image to grayscale.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but template/feature matching only seems to work if the object template and the object in the image are the same in terms of scale, rotation and intensity. This is how OpenCV docs explain it as well. I guess some modifications would be required to make it size/scale/color agnostic but not sure what.